# Sufficient Statistic for variance of a normal with 0 mean (factorisation of sample mass function)

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

I am going through an excercise on sufficient statistics and the factorisation theorem which states that the statistic $\mathbf{U} = h(\mathbf{Y})$ is a sufficient statistic for the parameter $\theta$ **if and only if** we can find functions $b$ and $c$ such that:

$f_{\mathbf{Y}}(y;\theta) =b(h(y), \theta)c(y) $

In the following example the book delivers a factorisation that I don't quite see how it fits into the form specified above—where one factor is a function of $h(y)$ and $\theta$, and the other only of $y$.

**Example given :**

A random sample $\mathbf{Y} = (Y_{1}\dots Y_{n})$, with $Y$ ~ $N(0,\sigma^{2})$.

The joint mass function of the sample can be factorised as follows:

$f_{\mathbf{Y}}(\mathbf{y} ; \sigma^{2}) = \displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt[]{2\pi \sigma^{2}}} \exp \left[ -\frac{y_{i}^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}\right] = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt[]{\pi\sigma^{2}}}\right)^{n}\exp\left[ -\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{i}^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}\right]$

This apparently tells us that the sum $\displaystyle\sum_{i}^{n}Y_{i}^{2}$ is sufficient for $\sigma^{2}$. But does this form really fit what is speciffied by the theorem above? What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, $b(h(y),\theta) = f_Y(y;\sigma^2)$ and $c(y) = 1$, so yes, the factorization holds and $h(y) = \sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2$ is sufficient.

Comment: But then wouldn't any factorisation work by  simply making $c(y) = 1$ ?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to show is a sufficient statistic. Consider the case of $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n\overset{\text{i.i.d.}}{\sim}\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$, with $\sigma^2$ being known. We seek a sufficient statistic for $\mu$. In this case, we can write out the PDF, $p_\mu(x)$, and factorize it as $c(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}^n}\exp\left(-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$ and $b(h(x),\mu) = \exp\left( -\frac{n\mu^2}{2\sigma^2} + \frac{\mu}{\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \right)$, showing $h(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ is sufficient.

Comment: In general, a sufficient statistic is useful in characterizing the coupling between the random vector $Y$ and the unknown parameter $\theta$. Therefore, you'd ideally like to minimize the information necessary to fully capture this coupling to preserve your ability to make inferences about $\theta$ with the least amount of information possible. Therefore, you can sort of think of $c(y)$ as being the dependence of the PDF on $y$ that doesn't really help with inferring information about $\theta$. There are plenty of examples in which $c(y)$ is nontrivial (see the above example I provided).